# Alternative proofs of Goursat's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Goursat's theorem** Suppose $G$ is an open connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and that $f$ has a complex derivative at every point in $G$ then $f$ is analytic in the sense that $f'$ is also continuous.

It seems like all proofs of Goursat's Theorem in complex analysis books are the same and apply some version of Moreras Theorem. (They are the same modulo the integration path in construction, i.e. rectangle, triangle e.t.c.)

Now since a complex valued function with complex derivative on an open domain of $\mathbb{C}$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann at every point we can use distribution theory to say that such a function must be holomorphic (see chapter 11 of Rudin).

[image]

(Edit: Maybe this is less obvious than what I indicate, Rudin assumes that $f$ is differentiable as a function from $\mathbb{R^2}$)

So this would work as an alternative proof of Goursat's Theorem I believe. **However I wonder if there is some simpler more elementary proof that does not rely on some form of Morera's Theorem?** (showing that the integral of the function over some family of contours is always zero)

Comment: "Now since a complex valued function with complex derivative on an open domain of C satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann at every point we can use distribution theory to say that such a function must be holomorphic " Just a minute - this is not nearly as simple as you seem to think. How  do  you get from CR at every point to CR **in the sense of distributions**? (For that matter, how do you know that $f$ is regular enough that it even defines a distribution in the first place?)

Comment: If  f has a complex derivative at every point, then it is continuous so it should be $L^1$ locally right? So it defines a distribution?

Comment: RIght on that one  - I was forgeting the hypothesis was that $f'$ exists. But you still need to  get somehow from pointwise to distibution CR -  that can't be easy, it's a huge surprise that it's true

Comment: It seems like Rudin assumes something stronger, that $f$ is differentiable as a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I though however that CR on an open set was enough for analyticity to be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, CR at every point of an open set implies analytic. But that''s far from trivial